# Prevent flicker - Lcd with I2C module?

Tags: i2c, nodemcu, lcd

I have a 16x2 LCD with a I2C interface, and a Esp8266 based NodeMCU.

I Have an issue where the second line of the LCD is flickering, but somehow the first line does not flicker.

Why does this happen and how do I prevent it?

My code :-

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h>
#include <NTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include "DHT.h"
#include "LiquidCrystal_PCF8574.h"
#include <EEPROM.h>

#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial
#define DHT_PIN_DATA  12
// LCD definations
#define LCD_ADDRESS 0x27
#define LCD_ROWS 2
#define LCD_COLUMNS 16
#define SCROLL_DELAY 150
#define BACKLIGHT 25
#define DHTTYPE DHT22

// You should get Auth Token in the Blynk App.
// Go to the Project Settings (nut icon).
char auth[] = "ymri80lbh9_xZhf6WIRHtQ1qHYOt9zBy";
char ssid[] = "DB";
char pass[] = "bkg88q";
int autoSch;
int waterNow;
int morTime;
int afterTime;
int postNoon;
int eveTime;
int schTime;
int minStep;
int interval;
int count;
int flag = 0;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;

DHT dht(DHT_PIN_DATA, DHTTYPE);
LiquidCrystal_PCF8574 lcdI2C;
WiFiUDP ntpUDP;
NTPClient timeClient(ntpUDP, "in.pool.ntp.org", 19800, 600000);
// This function will be called every time Slider Widget
// in Blynk app writes values to the Virtual Pin 1

BLYNK_CONNECTED() {
  Blynk.syncAll();
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V0)
{
  autoSch = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V1 to a variable
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V1)
{
  morTime = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V1 to a variable
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V2)
{
  afterTime = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V1 to a variable
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V6)
{
  postNoon = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V1 to a variable
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V3)
{
  eveTime = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V1 to a variable
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V10)
{
  waterNow = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V1 to a variable

}

BLYNK_WRITE(V4)
{
  schTime = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V1 to a variable
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V7)
{
  minStep = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V1 to a variable
}

void setup()
{
  dht.begin();
  lcdI2C.begin(LCD_COLUMNS, LCD_ROWS, LCD_ADDRESS, BACKLIGHT);
lcdI2C.setBacklight(2);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  pinMode(14, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(14, LOW);
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 0);
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V8, 0);
  pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  EEPROM.begin(512);
  //WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass);
  while ( WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED ) {
    delay ( 500 );
    Serial.print ( "." );
  }
  timeClient.begin();
  Blynk.syncAll();
}

void loop()
{
  Blynk.run();
  time_run();
  lcd();
  butPress();
  //test();
  timeClient.update();
  if (waterNow == 1) {
    waterNowrun();
  } else if (autoSch == 0) {
    auto_run1();
  } else if (autoSch == 1) {
    sch_run2();
  } else {
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V10, 0);
    digitalWrite(14, LOW);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 0);
    Blynk.syncAll();
  }
  Blynk.syncAll();
}


void lcd() {
  lcdI2C.clear();

  timeClient.update();
  lcdI2C.print(timeClient.getFormattedTime());

  if (autoSch == 0) {
    lcdI2C.setCursor(9, 0);
    lcdI2C.print("Auto");
  } else {
    lcdI2C.print(" Sch");
  }


  if (digitalRead(14) == 1) {
    lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
    lcdI2C.print("Wtr Now           ");
  }
  else
  {

    if (int(timeClient.getHours()) < 6 && morTime == 1 && autoSch == 0) {
      Blynk.syncAll();
      lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
      lcdI2C.print("Auto Wtr at: 6a");
    } else if (int(timeClient.getHours()) < 12 && afterTime == 1 && autoSch == 0) {
      Blynk.syncAll();
      lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
      lcdI2C.print("Auto Wtr at: 12n");
    } else if (int(timeClient.getHours()) < 14 && postNoon == 1 && autoSch == 0) {
      Blynk.syncAll();
      lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
      lcdI2C.print("Auto Wtr at:14pn");
    } else if (int(timeClient.getHours()) < 18 && eveTime == 1 && autoSch == 0) {
      Blynk.syncAll();
      lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
      lcdI2C.print("Auto Wtr at: 18e");
    } else if (int(timeClient.getHours()) >= 18 && morTime == 1 && autoSch == 0) {
      Blynk.syncAll();
      lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
      lcdI2C.print("Auto Wtr at: 6a");
    } else {

    }

  }

}

void waterNowrun() {
  interval = minStep * 60 * 1000;
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  Serial.println (currentMillis);
  Serial.println (previousMillis);
  Blynk.syncAll();
  if (((currentMillis - previousMillis) >= interval) || waterNow == 0) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V10, 0);
    digitalWrite(14, LOW);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 0);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V8, 0);
    Blynk.syncAll();
  } else {
    digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 255);
    lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
    lcdI2C.print("Wtr Now :");
    lcdI2C.print((minStep * 60) - ((currentMillis - previousMillis) / 1000));
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V8, ((interval / 1000) - ((currentMillis - previousMillis) / 1000)));
    Blynk.syncAll();
  }
}

void sch_run2() {
  if (schTime == 1) {
    digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 255);
    Blynk.syncAll();
  } else if (schTime == 0) {
    digitalWrite(14, LOW);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 0);
    Blynk.syncAll();
  }

}

void time_run() {
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V11, int(timeClient.getHours()));
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V12, int(timeClient.getMinutes()));
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V13, float(dht.readTempC()));
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V14, float(dht.readHumidity()));

}

void butPress() {
  if (digitalRead(2) == LOW) {
    if (flag == 0) {


      flag = 1;
      digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(14, LOW);
      flag = 0;
    }
    int y = 10;
    int x = 0;
    if (digitalRead(14) == HIGH) {
      for (x = 0; x < y; x++) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.println("x:  ");         Serial.println(x);
      }
    }else{
      digitalWrite(14, LOW);
      }

  }
}

void test() {
  if (digitalRead(2) == LOW) {
    Serial.println("IDLY BLAA");
    int y = 10;
    for (int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
      delay(500);
      Serial.println("x:  ");         Serial.println(x);
    }
  }

}



void auto_run1() {
  if (morTime == 1 && String(timeClient.getFormattedTime()) > "06:00:00" && String(timeClient.getFormattedTime()) < "06:20:00") {
    digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 255);
    Blynk.syncAll();
  }
  else if (afterTime == 1 && String(timeClient.getFormattedTime()) > "12:00:00" && String(timeClient.getFormattedTime()) < "12:20:00") {
    digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 255);
    Blynk.syncAll();
  }
  else if (postNoon == 1 && String(timeClient.getFormattedTime()) > "14:00:00" && String(timeClient.getFormattedTime()) < "14:20:00") {
    digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 255);
    Blynk.syncAll();
  }
  else if (eveTime == 1 && String(timeClient.getFormattedTime()) > "12:59:00" && String(timeClient.getFormattedTime()) < "13:01:00") {
    digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 255);
    Blynk.syncAll();
  }
  else  {
    //(String(timeClient.getFormattedTime() == "06:20:00" || "12:20:00" || "14:20:00" || "13:48:00"))
    //waterNowrun();
    /*
      Blynk.virtualWrite(V10, 0);
      digitalWrite(14, LOW);
      Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 0);
      Blynk.virtualWrite(V8, 0);
      Blynk.syncAll();
    */
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't do `lcdI2C.clear();` on each loop. Just overwrite the existing contents. Then it does not flicker.

Comment: @PMF I just tried that, now the LCD is frozen

Comment: Frozen? As in: "Shows nothing at all"? I don't exactly know what kind of LCD library you use there, but it might be necessary to call the clear() once at startup.

Comment: @PMF Shows the information it should show, but does not update

Comment: You might need to do a `lcdI2C.setCursor(0, 0);` where the `clear()` was, to ensure you start at the top left with updating the lcd.

Comment: Now it works...  but there's another small problem- now if I physically disturb the LCD, it displays random characters.

Not a major issue, just want to know why.

Comment: I've seen LCDs behave unpredictably with bad cabling or a bad power source. So if moving the LCD causes contact problems, then this could be the cause. Make sure all cables are seated properly.

Comment: Alright, I did some digging around and found out it was due to high CPU frequency, case closed

Comment: one proposal. Give a good description about the problem you found. The solution you used. Answer your own question. It will be helpful for someone later.